# Ruby: Sales Tax puzzle - the items enumerator does not save when modified

Tags: ruby, oop, rspec

I was recently asked to complete Sales Tax problem using OOD in Ruby.  It's one of the typical technical test questions for job interviews.

For those who don't know - here's the brief synopsis of the problem.

> Basic sales tax is applicable at a rate of 10% on all goods, except
>   books, food, and medical products that are exempt. Import duty is an
>   additional sales tax applicable on all imported goods at a rate of 5%,
>   with no exemptions.
>
> When I purchase items I receive a receipt that lists the name of all
>   the items and their price (including tax), finishing with the total
>   cost of the items, and the total amounts of sales taxes paid. The
>   rounding rules for sales tax are that for a tax rate of n%, a shelf
>   price of p contains (np/100 rounded up to the nearest 0.05) amount of
>   sales tax.
>
> Write an application that prints out the receipt details for these
>   shopping baskets.

So away I went.  And I came up with the following.

In the Receipt.rb

```
class Receipt
    attr_accessor :items

    def initialize receipt_file = false
        @receipt_file = receipt_file
        @items = @receipt_file ? YAML::load(File.read(@receipt_file)) : []

    end

    def get_items_in_category books, food, medical_products
        @items.reject do |item|
            item.category == books || item.category == food || item.category == medical_products
        end
    end

    def get_items_that_are_imported isimported
        @items.select do |item|
            item.isimported == isimported
        end
    end

    def calculate_sales_tax 

         @items.each_with_index do |item, index|
            #puts items[index]
            if item.category != :books && item.category != :food && item.category != :medical_products

                item.cost = (0.1 * item.price) + item.price

            end

        end 
        binding.pry

    end
    /......./

    def get_total_sales_tax_all_items
        binding.pry
        @total_sales_tax = 0 

        @items.select do |item|
            unless item.cost == 0
                @total_sales_tax = @total_sales_tax + (item.cost - item.price)  
            end
        end

        return @total_sales_tax
    end

end
```

In the Item.rb

```
class Item
    attr_accessor :name, :quantity, :price, :cost, :category, :isimported
        def initialize name, quantity, price, cost, category, isimported
            @name = name
            @quantity = quantity
            @price = price
            @cost = cost
            @category = category
            @isimported = isimported
        end
end
```

Then in my receipt_spec.rb file

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Receipt object" do

    before :all do
        receipt_obj = [
            Item.new("book", 1, 12.49, 0, :books, false),
            Item.new("music cd", 1, 14.99, 0, :music, false),
            Item.new("chocolate bar", 1, 0.85, 0, :food, false)

        ]
        File.open "receipts.yml", "w" do |f|
            f.write YAML::dump receipt_obj
        end
    end

    before :each do
        @receipt = Receipt.new "receipts.yml"
    end
    .............

    it "calculate the sales_tax for each item" do

        @receipt.calculate_sales_tax

    end

end
```

The part that puzzles me the most is the Receipt's instance method calculate sales tax for each item in the receipt.  In my instance of the Receipt object **@receipt** already contains an enumerator of Item objects, **@items**.  When I ran the rspec and put binding.pry in the method, I can see that the @items object elements were modified whilst the calculate sales tax is still in the middle of its execution ie the cost for each item were calculated correctly.

However after exiting this method, and ran other rspec tests on receipts's get_total_sales_tax_all_items method, I debugged and found that the @receipt's items enumerator were not modified at all.  They still retain the old elements when @receipt object was instantiated.

Thus I'm confused why this is happening...  I tried using map or map! which is said to return the replaced values of your enumerator or array.  But the result remained the same.

Can someone please help to explain what I'm doing wrong here.  What I'm trying to achieve is not the right way of thinking??  I'm still new to OOD in Ruby so there must be something I don't fully get it in Ruby vs other languages.

Cheers!

Comment: Where does @receipt come from in your spec?

Comment: Sorry.  Forgot to add it to the spec.  It's there now!

Answer (score 0):

Each of your examples (the `it` blocks) creates a new `@receipt` object (as the name indicates, a `before(:each)` runs for each example).

It's normal therefore that your call to `calculate_sales_tax` has no effect on the other examples - they have their own receipt object.

This is the way it should be: your specs should be isolated from each other and you don't want them to have to run in a certain order to pass (rspec can run your specs in a random order to avoid this dependency creeping in)

Comment: Aha!! No wonder why it failed to work.  I never fully understood why the before:all and before:each statements were constructed like that.  After I changed before:each to before:all, it's now outputting the correct results I needed! Cheers!